# mkdir(): Permission denied after chmod

Tags: file-permissions, chmod, mkdir

I am faced with the `mkdir(): Permission denied` issue and i have checked multiple answers. All of them stated the permission of the storage folder shoulf be changed `sudo chmod -R 777 app/storage` but still the issue is not resolved in my case.

Any other solutions i should try to get it working?

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked ownership of the master directory? If for example, it's owned by `root:root` you'd only be able to access it as root, unless you used `chown` to change ownership.

Comment: I gave 777 to the whole app. What do you mean?

Comment: Permissions and ownership are two different things.

Comment: If you run an `ls -la` next to the directory you see `youruser:youruser`?

Comment: drwxrwxrwx@ 16 safwany  admin    544 Nov 20 13:59 .
is that what you mean?!

Comment: Are you part of the admin group?